# Update the database when changing the original input

Tags: php, mysql

In my database i have the following table

```
Aid | oid | prijs
```

In here the combination of aid & oid is the key. 
On the form to review the data, I download the data. Aid is fixed, but the oid value can be changed.

When i send the information for an update, I currently send along the 'old' values to know which row I have to update. I was wondering if there is a better solution to this, then creating a hidden field containing the current field information.

Any suggestions are more then welcome to make this more efficient.

Comment: You should have a static identificator, not old value.

Comment: With static identificator you mean an original 'key' which can be used for this? And if this is not the preferd solution. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: If your primary key is composite and one element of it changes, then you will have to reload the form (or update it via Ajax) to reflect the new key.

Comment: I mean a key that does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Aid + Oid is a composite primary key, then you will need both to be sure you are updating the correct row.

A hidden field is a reasonable way to do this. If your app uses rewritten urls, you could also control this through the POST url (like /update/{$aid}/{$oid} or similar).